# using AND condition MYsql

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

What I need is: when I give training_id 172 AND training_id 174 it have to return user 150 only

[image]

I tried this but it doen't work

```
SELECT user_id FROM Training_users WHERE training_id = 172 AND training_id = 174
```

Most of the times training_id might be more than 2

Comment: what is your primary key in this table?

Comment: both user_id and training_id

Comment: The problem is your PK is on both fields, so the uniqueness exists with both fields only, thus your querying approach is not going to work. You need to have user_id in your query too (`WHERE user_id=150`)

Comment: Please explain your question ..The given example makes your question confusing.

Comment: You are expecting user `150` in return. In other way, are you expecting the most latest `user_id` on the `training_id`s?

Comment: If you know that both `training_id`s have the same `user_id`, then what is the point of having them both in the query? You must know that they are the same, otherwise there wouldn't be a "correct" result the database could give you. Apologies if I have misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this query:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as nbTrainings FROM Training_users
WHERE training_id = 172 OR training_id = 174
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING nbTrainings = 2
```

It will filter the users having the training 172 or 174. Then it will count how many trainings each user returned has and only keep the one(s) with two trainings.

This supposed that a user cannot have multiple trainings 172 and/or 174

The advantage of this against the multiple self-joins is that you don't have to join multiple times for each training id if you want to filter with more than 2 training id.

More info on `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` [here](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlgroupby.php)

EDIT : After testing in sqlfiddle this seems to work and does not return wrong values if some users have multiple training_id and one being 172 or 174

Working [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4496c/1/0)

Comment: I thought this kind of solution too. Let's see if it is enough. I abandoned this because there can be a row with user 1 - > 172 and 65 then user 2 -> 174 and 42. This query should output both user 1 and 2.

Comment: @iiro : Just tested it in sqlfiddle, this seems to work. It does not count the number of trainings other than the ones in 172/174 because the rows are already filtered out.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right :)

Comment: Thank you my friend I think this might work. I have to try it in returning multiple users to see if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT a.user_id FROM Training_users a, Training_users b WHERE a.training_id = 172 and a.user_id = b.user_id AND b.training_id = 174;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
  a.user_id
FROM
  Training_users a
RIGHT JOIN
  Training_users b ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND b.training_id = 174
WHERE
  a.training_id = 172
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id from work where training_id in (172,174) group by user_id  having count(*)  > 1;
```

Check [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c305a/12)

Answer (score -3):

Do something like this

```
SELECT user_id FROM Training_users WHERE (training_id = 172) AND (training_id = 174)
```

Comment: that will return also another user ids

Comment: @iiro not said required unique user id

Comment: @Vineet1982 "it have to return user 150 only"

Comment: This is like -> SELECT user_id FROM Training_users WHERE training_id IN (172 , 174)